# excel - dynamic summing of columns

Tags: excel, indexing, sumifs

I would like to be able to pair INDEX-MATCH (or VLOOKUP) functionality with that of SUMIFS.  In the example linked below, I would like to look up data from a table if it matches a name reference (for the row) and sum all expenses by that individual for any given month.

Output 1): Allows me to be dynamic by the name reference and month reference but does not sum but rather stops on the first "Jan" it sees.

Output 2: Sums all the months but is not dynamic when I change the name.

Has anyone run into this before?  I could not find any answers online.

[image: Image of what I am describing]

Comment: Will your months in row 2 be excel dates formatted to only show the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

In cell C9 use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$5=$B8)*($C$2:$H$2=C$7)*$C$3:$H$5)
```

Comment: Very cool.  This works even better than I expected as this formula can even be used if there are multiples in the row names.  Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non array formula:

```
=SUMIF($2:$2,C$8,INDEX($A:$DDD,MATCH($B9,$B:$B,0),0))
```

The `INDEX($A:$DDD,MATCH($B9,$B:$B,0),0))` chooses the correct row, the first where the names match, and sets that row as the location of the values to sum for the SUMIF().

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This works very well.  Now just need to reverse engineer exactly what's going on :p

Comment: @b-poe there are advantages and disadvantages to both methods.  Which ever your chose to use please mark that one as the correct one by clicking the check mark by the appropriate answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder Scott.  Are the benefits of your method that the data can expand and the formula still picks up the changes?

Comment: The advantages of mine is it is not an array formula and can use full column and row references, while SUMPRODUCT needs to be confined to the extents of the data or the calc times will be long.  Also if there is a large dataset this will be faster.  The disadvantage is that this will not work with SUMIFS() so you are stuck with just the two criteria.  And as you noticed it will only grab the first line in which the name appears, if the names get duplicated and not sorted then you will need to go with @ForwardEd.